# I can't control my Dell's brightness

Tags: windows-7, brightness

I bought new Dell Inspiron 3521 with Linux installed. I've installed Windows 7. Everything would be alright but I can't brighten my screen. It looks like it is at the lowest brightness level. The Quickset driver is installed. There is no brightness level option in the Control Panel.

Maybe someone knows what's wrong?

Comment: I added the Windows tag since it seems like your problem is in Windows. Have you installed the drivers for your system from the Dell website?

Comment: Yes, all drivers are installed.

Comment: http://www.jdhodges.com/blog/dell-brightness-control-fn-hotkeys-stuck/ - this works for me

Answer (score 3):

On the keyboard, you should see a key by Ctrl and the Windows key labeled "Fn", hold down Fn and look for the [brightness display buttons](http://onlinetechguru.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/550px-LowerBrightness-Step-1.jpg) on your keyboard.  After looking at a few [images](http://ipon.hu/GalleryMod/2013-03/184732/259657_dell_inspiron_3521_touch_fekete_151872.jpg) through Google, I'm fairly certain that it should be F4 for dimming, F5 for brightening.  I haven't had much experience working with that specific model, so I can't recommend any Software that would fix the issue that you are having, but unless the Fn key is disabled somehow, that should allow you to brighten the screen to a desired level.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Fn key is working normally (with volume and other options). When I use fn to bright up my screen, I see (on the desktop) that screen brightness is in the highest level. When I'm trying to dim, I can see brightness steps in the highest level. Unfortunately, it doesn't want to be adjusted.

Comment: @Pauliuks Maybe your webcam is picking up the ambient light in your room and automatically adjusting for it, similar to how some cellphones operate?  If this is the case, you can try to turn off the screens ability to automatically adjust: [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/turning-off-windows-7-auto-dimming-on-desktop/4954ba46-27a3-4415-9f00-d76056694334).  If you find your screen to be getting too bright/dim at certain points of the day, you can also try installing [F.lux](http://justgetflux.com/).

Answer (score 2):

1st.Update your bios version from dell download site. You can manually download and run the setup to update.
it will reboot your system and start updating your bios once update process complete it will restart and you may normally login.

2ndly you need to update your VGA driver, instead of downloading setup you need to update the driver from Device manager - expand VGA adapter -  right click on default adapter - Update driver software - and Search Automatically for driver software .

let update your vga online. once vga is updated, reboot your system, it must solv your problem.

(it worked with windows 7 32 bit.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you – not only brightness, but also some other functions are out of order just as the monitor changes from the HDMI port. I found a solution.

Go to [Intel Ivy Bridge and Sandy Bridge Graphic Driver For Windows 7](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS030279).

Download the graphics drivers from this site, and follow the steps to install them on your system. After that, restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it using the following [instructions](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-786937/increase-decrease-screen-brightness.html):

1. [Open the `Device Manager`](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/a-common-and-easy-way-to-access-device-manager-in-windows/) (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `devmgmt.msc` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Unfold `Monitors`, right-click the `PnP monitor` and `Uninstall` it.
3. Then right-click the computer (the root of the Device Manager tree) and select `Scan for hardware changes`.  The `PnP monitor` will be reinstalled and the brightness control should work.